# Is it possible to have regular logins and ActiveDirectory logins in the same ASP.NET app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, webforms

I currently have an app which using Active Directory for authentication.  In other words, the IIS virtual directory is setup Active Directory authentication and I do no have to deal with it at all.  If you are on the domain, you can get in.

Some customers now also want to add a feature where they can log in using a standard userid/password combo.  The scenario being a contractor coming in for a few days with their laptop and need access to the app.  There is no point of creating an Active Directory account for such a person.

Is this possible in an ASP.NET app?  How would I go about it?

Comment: In your Windows Authentication app, are you using custom Membership and Roles tables (i.e. the default ones built when running `aspnet_regsql`, or are you pulling all of that information from Active Directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you converted your app to use Forms Authentication, then you could configure 2 membership providers; one to authenticate against active directory, and the other could use the standard `SqlMembershipProvider`.  This second provider is the one you would create your temporary accounts in.

In regards to authenticating against multiple providers, this is quite straight-forward.  [This article](http://www.stevideter.com/2008/03/20/using-two-membership-providers-for-aspnet-logins/) describes the process.

Answer (score 1):

If you convert the application to use Forms Authentication, you can then process the login method to authenticate off of either Active Directory, or your own internal user database, depending on whatever criteria you expect. There are several articles out there on how to write your own code to perform a simple authentication against Active Directory.

Comment: I don't think that's going to work.  The customer still wants the users who have selected to remain with the ActiveDirectory model not to be annoyed with a login screen.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you probably want your own `Authentication Provider` as discussed in [this article](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/050216.htm). You'd build the validation logic to auth against the right store depending on your criteria.